# error: cannot decode model assertion eragon.model: assertion content/signature separator not found

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, snap

Created a kernel and gadget snaps successfully then building an ubuntu core image here it was showing this error. I just created .json model file for this image creation then Signed model assertion with my key using the below command 
$ cat eragon-model.json | snap sign -k default &> eragon.model

This command has been created a eragon.model file then I tried to build my board image using $ sudo /snap/bin/ubuntu-image -c devmode -o eragon410-SDtest.img eragon.model, here it was showing an error.

Does anybody know the solution.

Comment: Please add the detailed error along with your .json and .model file for debugging help.

Comment: sudo /snap/bin/ubuntu-image -c devmode -o eragon410-sd.img eragon.model 
error: cannot decode model assertion "eragon.model": assertion content/signature separator not found
COMMAND FAILED: snap prepare-image --channel=devmode eragon.model /tmp/tmp6gfsefr3/unpack

Comment: I was able to resolve the above issue, but now it was stopping at image creation, but gadget snap is created and added in the same path. But still showing below error                                                                                                                      sudo /snap/bin/ubuntu-image -c beta -o eragon410_sd.img eragon.model
error: cannot find snap "eragon410-gadget": snap not found
COMMAND FAILED: snap prepare-image --channel=beta eragon.model /tmp/tmp517vlo4b/unpack

Comment: Could you please help us on this? We struct at here and no movement.

Answer (score 1):

the -c or --channel options need to point to an existing channel in the store.
valid names would be edge, beta, candidate or stable.

also, if your eragon410-gadget snap is not in the store yet, you need to use the --extra-snaps option to point out to ubuntu-image that there is a local snap you want to use (the same goes for the kernel snap) instead of having it look at the store.